# What is "the tit of trouble" in Demon Copperhead?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> First, I got myself born. A decent crowd was on hand to watch, and they’ve always given me that much: the worst of the job was up to me, my mother being let’s just say out of it. On any other day they’d have seen her outside on the deck of her trailer home, good neighbors taking notice, pestering the **tit of trouble** as they will. (Barbara Kingsolver, *Demon Copperhead*)

Does the author mean tits as boobs? (Considering that she is a new mom.) But why would it be described as tit of *trouble*? What is the author trying to deliver here?

Comment: I can't really give a conclusive answer without knowing more about the source, but words like "breast", "teat", or "tit" are often used metaphorically in English, to mean e.g. a source of nourishment or source of other things.

Comment: The reader could associate the mild vulgarity of the word with the vulgarity of trailer trash the writer mentions

Comment: The author may be alluding to the fact that she is a new mom, but such a link seems fairly tenuous. (The author's mother "pesters the tit of trouble" on "any other day", not on the day of the author's birth, so there seems to be little direct connection to that event, also.)

Comment: Barbara Kingsolver was raised in Appalachian Kentucky, and she still lives in Appalachia. They speak a distinctive dialect of English in Appalachia, and the language of the book is heavily influenced by it. I doubt this *tit* has anything to do with boobs, but the only way to figure out what it actually means is to find a reference on Appalachian English or to ask somebody who knows it. Kingsolver can write perfectly in standard english when she wants to.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google Books finds just 5 written instances of ***tit of trouble*** where those words can be read in context, and they're all from the same source as cited by the OP here. The sequence has no currency, and no obvious meaning either.

Comment: Maybe this belongs in https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is speculatory, and it's possible a better answer may come along.

My guess is that this is figurative; it doesn't seem to be a set expression or phrase. (Kingsolver is known for her flowery prose, so it sort of fits with what I know of her style.)

In mammals, the *tit*, or *teat*, releases milk when stimulated. Presumably, **the *tit of trouble*, when *pestered*, dishes out hardship or strife.**

I'm not quite sure what it means here, but it seems that her neighbors have seen her tempting trouble on that deck.

Comment: Yes. That more general, literal use of the word "tit" is rather old-fashioned, but in a literary context you can get away with it.